# dynamic ip to hostname mapping in LAN

Tags: linux, ip, lan, hostname

I want to access PC in LAN from other devices. I cannot use static ip for my PC. Is there a way to use hostname instead of dynamic ip to access PC so that even if ip changes i can access PC with its hostname? I am usin Linux.

Comment: [Sigh.](http://superuser.com/questions/800492/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname-instead-of-dyna)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the hostname for the PC's and use SSH to access them.

Comment: Just setting the hostname on the computer itself is not enough; other computers still need a way to query for it. Windows has that built in – Linux often needs additional software.